# Timer service remove task

Tags: android, android-service

Здраствуйте , у меня есть service timer после запуска спустя некоторые время timer обновляется и в console следующую ошибку

```
remove task
failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 12520
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

сама задача передавать каждую секунду время и отображать в `progress bar`

```
public class AlarmService extends Service 

public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "gostudent.gostudent.Service.Timer_Activity";
private Handler handler; 
private long initial_time;
private long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    initial_time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}

// Send intent to broadcast
private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {

    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - initial_time;
    long timer =  timeInMilliseconds / 1000L;
    intent.putExtra("time", timer);
    long m = timer / 60L;

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Не нужно удалять аналогичные вопросы и задавать новый каждый день. Я ж вам в пролый раз ответил как сделать.

Comment: да я знаю огромное спасибо но у меня не получилась :((((( и за этого решил добавить код , для болие ясности